# How can I compute the difference between array values, then average them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I'm trying to do this in a functional way so although there are some methods I can already think of, I suspect there's a more elegant map/reduce-style technique.

Given an array like this:

```
[0, 47.22, 72.65, 126.93, 155.02, 307.46, 410.02, 417.21, 
 507.86, 510.466, 580.88, 661.29, 685.14, 695.86, 780.94,
 913.2, 1352.33, 1382.99, 1435.73, 1462.03, 1495.38, 1518.03,
 1523.58, 1544.3, 1591.21, 1612.03, 1665.99, 1672.62, 11.02, 22.791]
```

I want to compute the difference between each item and its following value, eg:

```
[47.22, 25.43, 54.28] // etc
```

(these values are timestamps for chat messages – I want to effectively see how long gaps were between messages, and then calculate the average for this user).

I was looking at `reduce()` but struggling to see how to make it do what I need. Is there an elegant way to do this or is my best bet a `for` loop which looks ahead to the next array item and does the calculation there?

Comment: Why not use a `forEach`? Also, I'm interested to see what approaches you have already tried.

Comment: what about negative deltas?

Comment: @MattAndrews For computing average how do you propose to handle negative differences?

Comment: Good point – for now there shouldn't be any as these numbers are ordered sequentially, but you never know with data...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution using `reduce`. This function returns a sensible `NaN` result when the average is not computable.

This data computes to an incorrect answer of `0.7858965517241373` because the input data is unordered which makes no sense. If you sort the data you get a more sensible `31.48965517241379` seconds average delta.

```js
const averageDelta = ([x,...xs]) => {
  if (x === undefined)
    return NaN
  else
    return xs.reduce(
      ([acc, last], x) => [acc + (x - last), x],
      [0, x]
    ) [0] / xs.length
};

let timestamps = [
  0, 47.22, 72.65, 126.93, 155.02, 307.46, 410.02, 417.21, 
  507.86, 510.466, 580.88, 661.29, 685.14, 695.86, 780.94,
  913.2, 1352.33, 1382.99, 1435.73, 1462.03, 1495.38, 1518.03,
  1523.58, 1544.3, 1591.21, 1612.03, 1665.99, 1672.62, 11.02, 22.791
]

console.log(averageDelta(timestamps))        // 0.7858965517241373
console.log(averageDelta(timestamps.sort())) // 31.48965517241379
```

But you tagged this question with `functional-programming` so you're probably looking for a better solution. The above answer is fine but it mixes concerns of several basic arithmetic computations. `averageDelta` is computing *difference*, *sum*, and *mean average* all in one function – what a mess!

Below we will implement a function for each of those things separately so that we don't have to think so hard. You'll also notice I took care to ensure each function is a [total function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function) which works on *all* inputs of its domain. This means `average` and `delta` will return sensible results for empty arrays, single-number arrays, and of course arrays with more than one number.

```js
const add = (x,y) =>
  x + y
  
const sum = xs =>
  xs.reduce(add, 0)

const average = xs =>
  xs[0] === undefined ? NaN : sum(xs) / xs.length

const delta = ([x,...xs]) =>
  xs.reduce(([acc, last], x) => [[...acc, x-last], x], [[], x]) [0]

let timestamps = [
  0, 47.22, 72.65, 126.93, 155.02, 307.46, 410.02, 417.21, 
  507.86, 510.466, 580.88, 661.29, 685.14, 695.86, 780.94,
  913.2, 1352.33, 1382.99, 1435.73, 1462.03, 1495.38, 1518.03,
  1523.58, 1544.3, 1591.21, 1612.03, 1665.99, 1672.62, 11.02, 22.791
]

console.log(average(delta([])))                // NaN
console.log(average(delta([1])))               // NaN
console.log(average(delta(timestamps)))        // 0.7858965517241373
console.log(average(delta(timestamps.sort()))) // 31.48965517241379
```

> Warning: `timestamps.sort()` uses `Array.prototype.sort` which mutates the original array. Considering sorting wasn't talked about in the original post, I'll leave that as a problem for you to solve, if it even is one.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time with this to get it right – have changed my accepted answer as this is the kind of thing I was trying to aim for but lack the ability to write on my own. Will digest this and implement! Thank you.

Comment: Very nice function. Love the ES6.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `reduce()` like this.

```js
var data = [0, 47.22, 72.65, 126.93, 155.02, 307.46, 410.02, 417.21, 
 507.86, 510.466, 580.88, 661.29, 685.14, 695.86, 780.94,
 913.2, 1352.33, 1382.99, 1435.73, 1462.03, 1495.38, 1518.03,
 1523.58, 1544.3, 1591.21, 1612.03, 1665.99, 1672.62, 11.02, 22.791];
 
 var result = data.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  if(data[i+1]) r.push(Number((data[i+1] - e).toFixed(2)));
  return r;
 }, [])
 
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: doesn't compute the average – i know it seems petty to say that, but a complete answer would demonstrate the proper composition of the multiple computations.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and use only the values with predecessor.

```js
var array = [0, 47.22, 72.65, 126.93, 155.02, 307.46, 410.02, 417.21, 507.86, 510.466, 580.88, 661.29, 685.14, 695.86, 780.94, 913.2, 1352.33, 1382.99, 1435.73, 1462.03, 1495.38, 1518.03, 1523.58, 1544.3, 1591.21, 1612.03, 1665.99, 1672.62, 11.02, 22.791],
    delta = array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        i && r.push(a - aa[i - 1]);
        return r;
    }, []),
    average = delta.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }) / delta.length;

console.log(delta);
console.log(average);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and return difference between current and next item

```js
var arr = [0, 47.22, 72.65, 126.93, 155.02, 307.46, 410.02, 417.21, 
 507.86, 510.466, 580.88, 661.29, 685.14, 695.86, 780.94,
 913.2, 1352.33, 1382.99, 1435.73, 1462.03, 1495.38, 1518.03,
 1523.58, 1544.3, 1591.21, 1612.03, 1665.99, 1672.62, 11.02, 22.791];
var output = arr.map( function( item, index, arr ){ 
  return (arr[index+1] - arr[index]); 
});
output.splice(-1,1); //remove last item, it is NaN since it is a difference between undefined and 22.791
console.log("Diff is", output);
var average = output.reduce( function(curr,prev){ return curr+prev; })/output.length;

console.log("average", average);
```

Comment: In your code `item` is equal to `arr[index]`. your `map` performs 3 array reads per item in `arr`. And why compute the last item if you know you're always going to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `forEach` loop to add the difference between adjacent elements into a new array:

```js
var arr = [22, 47.22, 72.65, 126.93, 155.02, 307.46, 410.02, 417.21, 507.86, 510.466, 580.88, 661.29, 685.14, 695.86, 780.94,913.2, 1352.33, 1382.99, 1435.73, 1462.03, 1495.38, 1518.03,1523.58, 1544.3, 1591.21, 1612.03, 1665.99, 1672.62, 11.02, 22.791];

var result = {array:[], sum: 0, current: 0};

arr.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    this.current = ((array[index + 1] - element) || 0);
    this.sum += this.current;
    this.array.push(this.current.toFixed(3));
}, result);

console.log(result.array);
console.log("Average: ", (result.sum / result.array.length).toFixed(3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

**EDIT**:

Credit to @naomik for suggesting this - better to use `reduce` by *keeping all mutations local to the callback*

```js
var arr = [0, 47.22, 72.65, 126.93, 155.02, 307.46, 410.02, 417.21, 507.86, 510.466, 580.88, 661.29, 685.14, 695.86, 780.94,913.2, 1352.33, 1382.99, 1435.73, 1462.03, 1495.38, 1518.03,1523.58, 1544.3, 1591.21, 1612.03, 1665.99, 1672.62, 11.02, 22.791];

var result = arr.reduce(function(acc, element, index, array) {
    acc.sum += element - acc.prev;
    index && acc.array.push((element - acc.prev).toFixed(3));
    acc.prev = element;
    return acc;
}, {array:[], sum: 0, prev: arr[0]});

console.log(result.array);
console.log("Average: ", (result.sum / result.array.length).toFixed(3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: Thanks – I ended up going with something like this, but it still felt a little ugly having to do the `index + 1` stuff. I guess this is quite a specific use-case though.

Comment: @ downvoter: why don't you let us know the issue here?

Comment: @MattAndrews you feel that way because this code is poorly designed and arguably not written in a functional way. Your use case is not overly specific. See Nina's answer or my own for a better solution.

Comment: @kukkuz besides my remark above, your post doesn't provide a complete answer – ie, it does not compute the average of the deltas.

Comment: @naomik I did not add the average calculation as I had asked him in the comments to the question on how he plans to handle negative deltas

Comment: @kukkuz I don't really see how that's relevant – plus he answered you. but OK.

Comment: @naomik I edited the answer later on when I got the time. Hope the downvoter can remove it now... I'm not assuming it is you :)

Comment: @kukkuz do you realize you're basically performing a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) by hand? `forEach` encourages the use of side-affecting functions whereas `reduce` does not. See this comparsion {[gist: foreach.js, reduce.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a24a92deaf5f7cd43fb7443959665cbe)} – `reduce` keeps all mutations local to the callback but `forEach` leaks mutations out.

Comment: @naomik I'd been using `forEach` like this without realizing that! Thanks a million for teaching me a new thing here! Really appreciate it! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @kukkuz no problem. The last criticism I'd have about your code is your `array[index + 1] - element || 0` is really chaotic. This 1) performs an add, 2) does an array lookup which may result in `undefined` then 3) makes a subtraction regardless of the lookup value, then 4) if the difference happens to be a falsy value, use `0` instead. `forEach` and `reduce` is already doing a lookup on the array for each element, but this `index+1` adds another for each iteration. Considering `reduce` gives you a state variable to work with, there's no reason for multiple lookups per iteration.

Comment: @naomik yes, I get your point now :) Have edited my answer, but one issue - the first difference comes up as zero? Can you point out the issue for me ?

Comment: @kukkuz you set the initial `prev` value to `arr[0]` but when you do `arr.reduce(...)` the first `element` will be `0` so `element - acc.prev` is `0 - 0` which equals `0`. Keep working with it, you're on the verge of a profound understanding.

Comment: @naomik I found it! Used `index && acc.array.push(` to prevent the first difference coming in the array and using `arr[0]` in `prev` means it will not affect the `sum`. :) Really appreciate your suggestions - learned a lot today! :)

Comment: On a lighter note, I think I don't deserve the downvote now :D

Comment: @kukkuz nice work, you've cleaned it up heaps. Looking *back* in the array is much safer than looking *forward* because we can always remember where we came from but we have no idea what lies ahead – Next, if you look a little closer you'll next notice that `current` doesn't need to be in your `acc`. A good indicator of this is that you assign it as the first part of the `reduce` loop which means the previous value of `current` is completely discarded. Since it is immediately discarded, there's really no reason to pass it along.

Comment: @naomik have tweaked by removing `current`