# I have two arrays which contain other arrays. How can I compare each nested array in array1 with its counterpart in array2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

Sorry if my title is confusing, this is difficult to explain.

I have created a multiple choice exam. When a user submits the exam, the answers are collected and put in an array like so:

```
userSubmittedAnswers = [
  ['c'], // Q.1
  ['d'], // Q.2
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], // Q.3
  ['b'], // Q.4
  ['c', 'd'], // Q.5
  ['d'], // Q.6
]
```

Each array inside this array called answers contains the submitted answer for each question in the multiple choice. Some answers have more than 1 available answer so that's why question 3 and 5 for example have more than 1 value.

This array is sent to the server where I want to compare it to a similar array which has the Correct answers:

```
correctAnswers = [
  ['d'], // Q.1
  ['d'], // Q.2
  ['a', 'b', 'c'], // Q.3
  ['b'], // Q.4
  ['c', 'd'], // Q.5
  ['d'], // Q.6
]
```

What I want to achieve is comparing the submitted answers with the correct answers, but to make sure that I count how many of the nested arrays are incorrect and keep track of them so that I can highlight them to the user on the client. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is... Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce()` and `every()` and return object with incorrect answers and total number of incorrect answers.

```js
var userSubmittedAnswers = [
  ['c'], // Q.1
  ['d'], // Q.2
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], // Q.3
  ['b'], // Q.4
  ['c', 'd'], // Q.5
  ['d'], // Q.6
]

var correctAnswers = [
  ['d'], // Q.1
  ['d'], // Q.2
  ['a', 'b', 'c'], // Q.3
  ['b', 'a'], // Q.4
  ['c', 'd'], // Q.5
  ['d'], // Q.6
]


//Loop SubmittedAnswers array (result, currentElement, index)
var result = userSubmittedAnswers.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  //First check if both array with same index are equal in length if they are continue with every check else return false.
  var check = (e.length == correctAnswers[i].length) ? true : false;
  //Loop current element or array or e with every() that will return true or false if every element is found in element with same index inside correctAnswers array
  if (check) {
    check = e.every(function(a) {
      return correctAnswers[i].indexOf(a) != -1;
    });
  }
  //If check return false add that Q+(index+1) to incorrect array and increment total incorrect answers
  if (!check) {
    r.incorrect = (r.incorrect || []).concat('Q.' + (i + 1));
    r.total = (r.total || 0) + 1;
  }
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer it's much appreciated! I don't quite understand how this works. Would you mind adding some comments or explaining it briefly? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, thanks editing this to make it clearer. Really helps! This solution is almost perfect but isn't quite working on the arrays with multiple values. Take question 3 for example, there are 3 correct answers. If I enter one of the correct answers, the above solution doesn't recognise it as incorrect. It only recognises it as incorrect if I put 'd' which doesn't appear in the correctAnswers array. Do you know why that is happening?

Comment: Could you create fiddle for that example i am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I've done some investigating. The code is using ```return correctAnswers[i].indexOf(a) != -1``` and this means that for the arrays where there are multiple answers, this line returns true if any one of the correct answers is in there, as opposed to all of them. So ```[ '3b' ]``` will be marked as correct, when in fact the array should be ```[ '3a', '3b', '3c']```. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see, well i think simple length check should fix this. I updated my answer so try it.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

1. Use a `forEach` to loop through the `userSubmittedAnswers`

   ( **EDIT**: changed it to `reduce` as it is advisable to *keep all mutations (referring to usage of `result` here) local to the callback* - learned it while [answering to a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236191/how-can-i-compute-the-difference-between-array-values-then-average-them/40236421#40236421).)
2. Calculate into `result` the number/list of correct/incorrect answers, and also an array with elements of the form is helpful to bind data to your html markup (if you are using AngularJS for instance):

   ```
    {
      "correct": false,
      "answer": [
        "c"
      ]
    }
   ```

See demo below:

```js
var userSubmittedAnswers=[["c"],["d"],["a","b","c","d"],["b"],["c","d"],["d"]];
var correctAnswers=[["d"],["d"],["a","b","c"],["b"],["c","d"],["d"]];

var result = {correctNo: 0, incorrectNo: 0, 
              correct: [], incorrect: [], details: []};

userSubmittedAnswers.forEach(function(element, index) {
  var answer = {};
  
  // check if the answer is correct
  answer.correct = element.every(function(elem) {
    return correctAnswers[index].indexOf(elem) !== -1;
  });
  
  // track the number of correct & incorrect answers
  if(answer.correct) {
    this.correctNo++;
    this.correct.push(index+1);
  } else {
    this.incorrectNo++;
    this.incorrect.push(index+1);
  }
  
  // accumulate the details
  answer.answer = element;
  this.details.push(answer);
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

*Edited answer:*

```js
var userSubmittedAnswers=[["c"],["d"],["a","b","c","d"],["b"],["c","d"],["d"]];
var correctAnswers=[["d"],["d"],["a","b","c"],["b"],["c","d"],["d"]];

var result = userSubmittedAnswers.reduce(function(arr, element, index, array) {
  var answer = {};
  
  // check if the answer is correct
  answer.correct = element.every(function(elem) {
    return correctAnswers[index].indexOf(elem) !== -1;
  });
  
  // track the number of correct & incorrect answers
  if(answer.correct) {
    arr.correctNo++;
    arr.correct.push(index + 1);
  } else {
    arr.incorrectNo++;
    arr.incorrect.push(index + 1);
  }
  
  // accumulate the details
  answer.answer = element;
  arr.details.push(answer);
  return arr;
}, {correctNo: 0, incorrectNo: 0, correct: [], incorrect: [], details: []});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: @Zauber let me know your thoughts on this answer? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to help me. This is similar to the answer I accepted. I saw it first so went with it but I appreciate your time to help! Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You could transform subarrays into strings to make comparisons easyer :

```
var results = serSubmittedAnswers.map((item, index) => item.join("") === correctAnswers[index].join("") ? 0 : 1);
console.log(results.reduce((a,b) => a+b) + " bad answers");
results.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item === 1) console.log("Q" + (index+1))
}); // 2 bad answers
    // Q1
    // Q3
```